# Tangent space of $S_1$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, tangent-spaces

Let $(x,y) \in S^1$. Then we can calculate $$T_{(x,y)} S^1 = \{(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : ax + by = 0\} = span\{(y,-x)\}$$ But I read somewhere the tangent space is spanned by $y \partial_x - x \partial_y$. How does this follow from the above? I know that $\{\partial_x, \partial_y\}$ is a basis for $T_{(x,y)}\mathbb{R}^2$ but I don't know how to relate this to the calculation above.

Thank you.

Comment: also, the final equality is wrong (notational issue). It should say $T_{(x,y)}S^1= \dots=\text{span}\{(y,-x)\}$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Ah yes, thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vector $(y, -x)$ is being written “in coordinates” with respect to the basis $\{\partial_x, \partial_y\}$; it corresponds to the linear combination is $y \partial_x - x \partial_y$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So in this tangent space $\{e_1, e_2\}$ and $\{\partial_x, \partial_y\}$ are both bases, and here we are choosing the latter basis to represent our vector? It seems weird to me that we have two different bases which look like completely different objects. I get that there is the isomorphism which gives us this but still.. I suppose its something I have to get used to.

Comment: Could you say what $e_1$ and $e_2$ are? The tangent space is usually described by the span of $\partial_i$, the partial derivative in the direction of the coordinate $x_i$

Comment: I'm thinking of $e_1$ and $e_2$ as the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$, i.e. $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. Since the tangent space at any point of $S^1$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$, no?

Comment: Re your last point, no—the tangent space to the sphere is 1-dimensional