Computing basis for tangent space of circle
I am trying to explicitly compute the basis of tangent space of a point $p \in S^1$. I am working with the atlas $(U_i,\phi_i)_{i=1}^4$, where $U_i = \phi_i((-1,1))$, and the coordinate charts are:
$$\phi_1:(-1,1) \rightarrow U_1, \phi_1(x) = (x,\sqrt{1-x^2})$$
$$\phi_2:(-1,1) \rightarrow U_2, \phi_2(x) = (x,-\sqrt{1-x^2})$$
$$\phi_3:(-1,1) \rightarrow U_3, \phi_3(y) = (\sqrt{1-y^2},y)$$
$$\phi_4:(-1,1) \rightarrow U_4, \phi_4(y) = (-\sqrt{1-y^2},y)$$
I will present two ways of answering this. Let's start with $p \in U_1$, i.e., point in upper semicircle. Then, we have that $T_p S^1$ is spanned by $ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} |_{p} $, which is the directional derivative along the `coordinate curve', i.e. the curve $\phi_1:(-1,1) \rightarrow U_1 \subset S^1$, at the point $\phi_1^{-1}(p)$.

Now, $ \frac{\partial}{\partial x}|_{p}(f) = \frac{ d (f \circ \phi_1)}{dt}(t)|_{(t = \phi^{-1}(p))} $. By the chain rule, $(RHS) = (f_{x_1}, f_{x_2} )|_p {(1,\frac{-t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}})}^T = f_{x_1}(p) - \frac{t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} f_{x_2}(p)  $.


The second way involves 'working through the coordinates' and might give more precise information. We use the fact that $ \frac{\partial}{\partial x}|_{p}(f) = \frac{ d (f \circ \phi_1 \circ \phi_1^{-1} \circ \phi_1)}{dt}(t)$.

Now, $f \circ \phi_1:(-1,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a curve in coordinate space, and $\nabla (f \circ \phi_1)(t) = (f_{x_1}, f_{x_2}) (\phi_{1,x}', \phi_{1,y}')^T = f_{x_1}(\phi_1(t)) \cdot 1 + $$ f_{x_2}(\phi_1(t)) \cdot (-\frac{t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}})$.
Contrarily, $\phi_1^{-1} \circ \phi_1:(-1,1) \rightarrow (-1,1)$ is simply the identity, so has derivative $1$.
But then, at $t = \phi_1^{-1}(p)$, we have $f_{x_1}(\phi_1(t)) \cdot 1 + $$ f_{x_2}(\phi_1(t)) \cdot (-\frac{t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}) = f_{x_1}(p) + f_{x_2}(p) \frac{-x}{y} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}|_{p}(f)$.
Questions: Assuming my computation is correct, what is the proper way to denote the above basis vector as a functional? Is it $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}|_{p} = dx_1 + dx_2 \frac{-x}{y} $? But if it is this, in what sense can we say that $T_p S^1$ is spanned by one element? Aren't $dx_1$ and $dx_2$ (or, in general, derivative wrt. first and wrt. second argument) linearly independent?
I also apologize for any typographical nuisances and would appreciate any feedback/corrections on variable selection.

How did a tangent vector turn into a $1$-form? Tangent vectors act on functions; $1$-forms act on tangent vectors.

@TedShifrin my limited understanding is responsible for that. I’m not sure what the right form is. I anticipate now that it might be the vector $(1,-x/y)$, or the corresponding unit vector $(y,-x)$., which is the basis element from my above calculations (and this corresponds also to the actual tangent to a circle at a point).

@TedShifrin I also refer to another post, which says that the basis is $y \partial_x - x \partial_y$. Here's the link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4434018/tangent-space-of-s-1

Yes, that’s correct. $\partial_x$ is the vector field $(1,0)$ on $\Bbb R^2$. Very different from $dx$.

Ok, then that makes sense. But why is $\partial_x$ denoting $(1,0)$?

@TedShifrin In particular, what is the relationship between a partial derivative and a direction vector here?

Simple: The tangent vector $v$ at $p$ corresponds to the directional derivative at $p$ in direction $v$.
